# Java - javax.json - Compile Error: "cannot find symbol" for .getValueType() - Can't seem to figure out why

Tags: java, json, command-prompt, notepad

I have a database, and through my code I get my database into a JsonArray and start iterating through the JsonArray, (finding only JsonObjects). From there, I believe I have this setup so I can iterate through the properties of each JsonObject. However, each JsonObject contains Json Strings and Json Arrays. Right now, I'm experimenting so I tried to create a manual exception for the arrays, basically how I tried to have it setup is, only do your work, if you are dealing a Json String.

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.json.JsonStructure;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonValue;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DataTest
{
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{
    String strValue = "";
    JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileReader("Elements.JSON"));
    JsonObject jsonst = reader.readObject();

    JsonArray elements = jsonst.getJsonArray("Elements");
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) 
    {
        JsonObject element = elements.getJsonObject(i);
        Collection<String> elementValues = element.keySet();
        Iterator<String> elementKeys = elementValues.iterator();
        while(elementKeys.hasNext())
        {
        //Error is over here!!!
            if(elementKeys.next().getValueType().equals(JsonValue.ValueType.STRING))
            {
                String elementKey = (String)elementKeys.next();
                strValue = element.getString(elementKey);
                System.out.println(strValue);
            }
        }
    }

    reader.close();
}
}
```

I believe I have the right imports, however when I try to compile this the compiler gives me "cannot find symbol", at the .getValueType() method. (I left a comment stating "Error is over here!!!" in my code, the line with this method is right below that comment)

I've also checked the format of the comparison, the following is copy and pasted from: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.json.JsonString
if ((results.getValueType().equals(JsonValue.ValueType.STRING))

Here is a small portion of my database:

```
{
"Elements" : [
    {
    "name" : "Hydrogen",
    "Symbol" : "H",
    "atomicNumber" : "1",
    "electronegativity" : "2.2",
    "group" : "Hydrogen",
    "ionCharge1" : "1+",
    "ionCharge2" : "1-",
    "molarMass" : "1.01",
    "naturalState" : "Gas",
    "synthetic" : "false",
    "diatomic" : "true",
    "columnNumber" : "1",
    "row" : "1",
    "columnCode" : "IA",

    "nobleGasConfiguration" : [
        {
        "term:" : "No Noble Gas Configuration",
        "superScript" : "-"
        }
    ],
    "electronConfiguration" : [
        {
        "term" : "1s",
        "superScript" : "1"
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

I suspect this may be to do with things such as subinterface, superinterfaces, implemented class, etc, etc. Essentially trying to use a method with something that does not have access to that method. However, as to my understanding this should work.

Here is the api documents that you might need:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonValue.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html

To put my questions clearly down... Why is the compiler giving me a "cannot find symbol"? What do I have to change in my code to fix this?

What programs, version, etc am I using?

Notepad

Command Prompt

Java 8

javax.json-1.0.jar

Please keep the answers to javax.json and java.

Comment: `elementsKey.next()` returns you an String, which doesn't contain the method `getValueType()`. It might be that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because `elementKeys.next()` returns a `String`, which doesn't have a `getValueType()` method. You don't need the if check, and you don't need the cast in `(String)elementKeys.next();`. Just remove those and you should be fine.

Comment: I run into another problem if I do that (this problem is described in the reply that I made to the comment above)

Comment: Well that comment is now missing for some reason. I'm guessing it was deleted. So, the problem would then lie in strValue = element.getString(elementKey); What the plan is, I iterate through the json object values, assign that value to a string, then pass that string into an instance of an class. (that class is not made yet, so right now I am just out printing the string). The arrays hold strings that need to be formatted. I want to make sure the rest of the code is working fine first. I need the if statement to tell the program to skip the arrays.

Comment: the new error is I am trying to use .getString to get an array (once I reach the first array in the json object)